# keep info on top of page

Tags: html, css

I have a php page which displays a company telephone list. With option buttons to add and remove on the top of the page and the data below it.

Now when the user scrolls then of course the buttons move and then cant be clicked as they cant be seen.

Is there a way to make items stay on top of the page even when the user scrolls?

EDIT: I tried using position fixed but it overlaps my database displaying the information. Is there something im doing wrong?

my code:

```
<center>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.menu {
position: fixed;
height: 0px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
<title>Extension List</title></head><body>
<br>
<div class="menu">
<h1> Alpine Motors VW Extension List</h1>
<h2> Tel: 031 717 7800</h2>
<h2><a href="add.php">Add Extension</a>
<br>
<br>
<form action="AlpineExtensionList.php"  method='post'>
<input type="submit" value="Print PDF"/>
<br>
<br>
<a href="delete.php"> Delete Extension</a></h2>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<?php
```

The rest of the code is my database linking and displaying the data.

but the part above between the div i tried to create is what i need to be on top as the user scrolls.

Comment: You can try to use "position: fixed;" in the css

Comment: PHP is irrelevant to this. You want a "sticky" or fixed header, which is generated from HTML and CSS.

Comment: Refer to the following https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu

Comment: @Vbudo i tried using that. See my edited question sir. Must be something im doing wrong

Comment: @Qirel i did attempt it but it seems to be causing problems. Please see my edited question above.

Comment: @RedZ See this little example I've quickly wrapped together: https://jsfiddle.net/fLkrazj9/

Comment: @Qirel ty so much now i got it :)

Comment: @Qirel this worked but it took my database and lowered the width of it...now it isnt showing the cellphone numbers. but i have closed the div before the database started. So why is it affecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set the css position of the button to be fixed. This is just example:

```
#button
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 30px;
   right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: i tried that but the writing is overlapping now over my other information